# SP2013 - disable Search Result pop-up

Tags: search-results, popup

I have configured a page with OOB Search Results webpart. It works as excpected but I want to disable the "pop-up" dialog when mouseover the results.

Beside using CSS to hide it, do Sharepoint provide better way to disable the feature? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the hover cards which SP provides by itself. 
SharePoint uses 2 different display templates for showing the results. One of them is for the search results and the other for the hover display. 
Removing the reference of hover display template should suffice your requirement.